# Wordpress unable to override @media query in css

Tags: css, wordpress

I tried to override the @media query either using *child css* and *customize css function from wp interface*.

I attach below the code I found in the parent css file.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px){
.content-both-sidebars .content-area{float:none !important;width:100% !important;left:auto !important;border-width:0 !important}
.content-both-sidebars:not(.separate-layout) .content-area{padding:0 !important;margin-bottom:40px}
.content-both-sidebars .widget-area.sidebar-primary,.content-both-sidebars .widget-area.sidebar-secondary{float:left;width:49% !important; left:auto !important; padding:0 !important}
.content-both-sidebars .widget-area.sidebar-primary{float:right}
.content-both-sidebars:not(.separate-layout) .widget-area.sidebar-primary,.content-both-sidebars:not(.separate-layout) .widget-area.sidebar-secondary{width:48% !important}
.separate-layout.content-both-sidebars .content-area{margin-bottom:20px}
.separate-layout.content-both-sidebars .widget-area.sidebar-primary,.separate-layout.content-both-sidebars .widget-area.sidebar-secondary{width:49% !important}
.separate-layout.content-both-sidebars .widget-area.sidebar-secondary{margin-bottom:20px}
.separate-layout.content-both-sidebars .widget-area.sidebar-primary{padding-left:0}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1080px){
.content-both-sidebars .content-area{float:none !important;width:100% !important;left:auto !important;border-width:0 !important}
.content-both-sidebars:not(.separate-layout) .content-area{padding:0 !important;margin-bottom:40px}
.content-both-sidebars .widget-area.sidebar-primary,.content-both-sidebars .widget-area.sidebar-secondary{float:left;width:49% !important; left:auto !important; padding:0 !important}
.content-both-sidebars .widget-area.sidebar-primary{float:right}
.content-both-sidebars:not(.separate-layout) .widget-area.sidebar-primary,.content-both-sidebars:not(.separate-layout) .widget-area.sidebar-secondary{width:48% !important}
.separate-layout.content-both-sidebars .content-area{margin-bottom:20px}
.separate-layout.content-both-sidebars .widget-area.sidebar-primary,.separate-layout.content-both-sidebars .widget-area.sidebar-secondary{width:49% !important}
.separate-layout.content-both-sidebars .widget-area.sidebar-secondary{margin-bottom:20px}
.separate-layout.content-both-sidebars .widget-area.sidebar-primary{padding-left:0}
}
```

What I need to do is override the first one, that is the (max-width: 1280px), and let the second one only working. I was able to do this removing the code lines in the parent css, but I am not able to do the same thing working on child theme or on the css customization in wp interface.

May someone help please?

Comment: Do you know? it only works when your window size is `1080px` or less

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I know. With both instructions (1280 and 1080 ones) it was moving my sidebars below the content when the screen was less than 1280; what I want to do is obtain that result when screen is less than 1080.

Comment: for quick result we need graphical representation also or you can create a snippet for this

Comment: In my website I have 2  sidebars (left and right), I would like them to go below content only if window size is 1080px or less

Comment: -Is the sidebars are absolute?
-Which framework you are using? bootstrap or any other framework!

Comment: I use oceanwp theme with elementor; the sidebars are the theme ones and I uploaded a template created by elementor into them.

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

```
@media all and (max-width: 1280px){
.content-both-sidebars .content-area{float:none !important;width:100% !important;left:auto !important;border-width:0 !important}
.content-both-sidebars:not(.separate-layout) .content-area{padding:0 !important;margin-bottom:40px}
.content-both-sidebars .widget-area.sidebar-primary,.content-both-sidebars .widget-area.sidebar-secondary{float:left;width:49% !important; left:auto !important; padding:0 !important}
.content-both-sidebars .widget-area.sidebar-primary{float:right}
.content-both-sidebars:not(.separate-layout) .widget-area.sidebar-primary,.content-both-sidebars:not(.separate-layout) .widget-area.sidebar-secondary{width:48% !important}
.separate-layout.content-both-sidebars .content-area{margin-bottom:20px}
.separate-layout.content-both-sidebars .widget-area.sidebar-primary,.separate-layout.content-both-sidebars .widget-area.sidebar-secondary{width:49% !important}
.separate-layout.content-both-sidebars .widget-area.sidebar-secondary{margin-bottom:20px}
.separate-layout.content-both-sidebars .widget-area.sidebar-primary{padding-left:0}
}

@media all and (max-width: 1080px){
.content-both-sidebars .content-area{float:none !important;width:100% !important;left:auto !important;border-width:0 !important}
.content-both-sidebars:not(.separate-layout) .content-area{padding:0 !important;margin-bottom:40px}
.content-both-sidebars .widget-area.sidebar-primary,.content-both-sidebars .widget-area.sidebar-secondary{float:left;width:49% !important; left:auto !important; padding:0 !important}
.content-both-sidebars .widget-area.sidebar-primary{float:right}
.content-both-sidebars:not(.separate-layout) .widget-area.sidebar-primary,.content-both-sidebars:not(.separate-layout) .widget-area.sidebar-secondary{width:48% !important}
.separate-layout.content-both-sidebars .content-area{margin-bottom:20px}
.separate-layout.content-both-sidebars .widget-area.sidebar-primary,.separate-layout.content-both-sidebars .widget-area.sidebar-secondary{width:49% !important}
.separate-layout.content-both-sidebars .widget-area.sidebar-secondary{margin-bottom:20px}
.separate-layout.content-both-sidebars .widget-area.sidebar-primary{padding-left:0}
}
```